# Chaining functions for cleaner code

Tags: python

I have the following functions that I would like to be able to chain together for usage to have cleaner code:

```
def label_encoder(dataframe, column):
    """
    Encodes categorical variables
    """
    le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
    le.fit(dataframe[column])
    dataframe[column] = le.transform(dataframe[column])
    return dataframe

def remove_na_and_inf(dataframe):
    """
    Removes rows containing NaNs, inf or -inf from dataframes
    """
    dataframe.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan, inplace=True).dropna(how="all", inplace=True)
    return dataframe

def create_share_reate_vars(dataframe):
    """
    Generate share rate to use as interaction var
    """
    for interval in range(300, 3900, 300):
        interval = str(interval)
        dataframe[interval + '_share_rate'] = dataframe[interval + '_shares'] / dataframe[interval + '_video_views']
    return dataframe

def generate_logged_values(dataframe):
    """
    Generate logged values for all features which can be logged
    """
    columns = list(dataframe.columns)

    for feature in columns:
        try:
            dataframe[str(feature + '_log')] = np.log(dataframe[feature])
        except AttributeError:
            continue
    return dataframe
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
new_df = reduce(lambda x, y: y(x), reversed([label_encoder, remove_na_and_inf, create_share_reate_vars, generate_logged_values]), df)
```

but since the first function takes two arguments this will not work.  Any solutions to this, or maybe a completely different paradigm?

Comment: how do you get the value for column in label_encoder?

Comment: just something i know ahead of time depending on the data set.  i guess i could hardcode it?

Comment: yes, or make it at least have a default value...

Comment: what are you trying to get out of the chaining?  Are you trying to be able to easily add and remove from the chain?  Why not just call the functions in order with the result of the previous one?

Comment: i guess im trying to get a one-liner instead of having to call the functions in order with the result of the previous one

Comment: funca(funcb(funcc(funcb(df,column))))) is a one liner...  And it chains them.  If you just want it, because you want it, then this works.  But honestly, going for a 'one line' without any useful reason is probably not what you want to do.  Your code will probably be more clear calling each function on it's own line.

Comment: there are things you could do with decorators and treating functions as first class objects that could automate building the chain.  But I would only do that if you were trying to achieve specific goals, like being able to change the chain quickly and easily by simply writing new functions.  But this is a lot of extra work if you don't have a good reason to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could partially evaluate `label_encoder` first using functools.partial, and then use that version to parse to your lambda. E.g.

```
from functools import partial
fixed_col_bound_encoder = partial(label_encoder, column=2)
new_df = reduce(lambda x, y: y(x), reversed([fixed_col_bound_encoder, remove_na_and_inf, create_share_reate_vars, generate_logged_values]), df)
```